# Catch C runtime function calls with Sysinternals.ProcMon

Tags: c, function, filter, runtime, procmon

Is there a way to get `_stat()` C runtime functions caught in ProcMon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, because (as @Preet Sangha explained) it works below the CRT level. However, it does show you a call stack, and `_stat` does access a file. So if ProcMon has access to your executable symbols and you know which file to watch, you might see `_stat` in the call stack of that file's access.

If that is not enough, further describe your scenario.

Note that there are tools for hooking at the code level - see [How can I hook Windows functions in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873658/how-can-i-hook-windows-functions-in-c-c)

Comment: thank you, I'm using _stat to test if directory is present. I presume I may filter directory name access?

Comment: @Chesnokov, sure. On the filter window, Path => contains => the_dir_name

Comment: @Chesnokov, it works for me. Does the filter's list have a row that looks like "Path contains dir_name include"? Note that dir_name can be just the last subdir, and not the complete path. Also, try to access that dir using, say, the browser (which is what I just did). If you see nothing, the filter's not set correctly. If you do see the access, the code might not be accessing that dir after all. If that's the case, try monitoring all FileSys activity of the process, if it's not to much, and add filters based on the results.

Comment: thank you for your kind help, adding just last directory name as to be contained in Path works well with Windows Explorer. I'm sure the code should access that folder with `_stat` as the folder parameter passed is hard coded. The problem is that the process is IIS (w3wp.exe) and it calls native dll using interop. Native dll calls `_stat` to check if specific dir is present. I can not find that dir in Path column

Comment: @Chesnokov, are you sure the path is accessible to IIS? If it's on a non-existent drive, or a bad UNC path, or a mapped network drive that is not mapped to the user under which IIS is running, then ProcMon won't catch the dir access.

Comment: @eran, yes, the path is on c:\ drive, and I can catch all IIS filesys events in ProcMon. The logic in native dll is: test if specific dir is available on c:\ and drive, if not then use '.' current path to save error log. Thus I catch log file creation event in ProcMon where '.' is IIS path on c:] drive

Comment: @Chesnokov, I'm assuming `_stat()` returns -1. What's the last error when this happens? Also, if you want to check accessibility, you can use [_access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy(v=VS.100).aspx) - `if (_access(dir, 2) == 0) WriteLogTo(dir);`. Internally, it uses a different Win32 function. Maybe that will broaden the picture.

Comment: @eran, there is no W access file system right for native dll invoked from IIS, thus you can not create file in any desired place. There is possibility to create it in APPDATA but to get that folder you need to call `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` which is also no longer possible in w7

Comment: @eran, I presume I will use winapi functions to test for directory presence and capture that event in ProcMon

Comment: @Chesnokov, if you don't have write access, how can you create logs there? Anyway, both call WinApi functions - `_stat` calls `FindFirstFile`, and `_access` calls `GetFileAttributes` IIRC. But from what you say now about IIS, it's possible that the check is rejected before it gets to the actual dir, so you don't see the dir's access. I have no idea how those Win32 functions are implemented. Maybe you can give the IIS user permissions for that dir, and see if that works.

Comment: @eran, I create logs from web application only. native dll is used for some calculations taking the file from some folder. I found `CreateFile` event only for both `_stat` and `GetFileAttributes`

Answer (score 1):

ProcMon intercepts calls at the Window levels (specifically NTxxxx and ZWxxxx calls I think). These are way lower than the C runt time library - so I suspect no.

Comment: thank you for the answer, are there a C runtime functions monitors?