# Displaying Normal Applications in 3D Engine

Tags: graphics

So I have been picturing this 3D environment where I can open up my applications and just do stuff there. I'm thinking is this possible? I noticed that Googling it is harder than I thought. I did come accross http://awesomium.com/

I did have a computer graphics class and I created my own 3D world with OpenGL3, so I know my question might be a bit 'out there'. But then again, drag and drop web interfaces were 'out there' as well with the first few internet technologies.

So my question is: is it possible to open applications in a 3D environment? Is there a 3D engine that does this? If there is not a 3D engine, then what beginning steps would I need to take in order to program it (even if it's just for one program like notepad for example).

I'm curious. I'm noticing that when displaying 3D holograpic projections will become a possibility then this will be a very relevant question. For now I am just curious, I want to program my own space that opens some applications near a tree. I know the basics of programming and OpenGL, but I can't quite figure it out how to combine it.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You need to capture the output of the window of an application and render that to a texture. To do this you need hooks to for example intercept the WM_PAINT window message and hook in your code that captures what was painted on that window.

If you want to capture the output of a window that uses DirectX or OpenGL that does the rendering, you would need to (again, with hooks) intercept the method that flips the back buffer and displays the output. This is much harder to accomplish since you need to know per application what that method is.

The answer to your question should be along those lines, but as you can see, there is no one-size-fits-all solution to your question.

For more information on hooks: [How can I hook Windows functions in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873658/how-can-i-hook-windows-functions-in-c-c)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's really helpful :) In the meantime I also found these 2 examples to see what is possible: http://famo.us/ (3D apps) and a 3D text editor https://bloomeditor.com/