# Is it possible to get the thread Id of a process that is listening to a Port in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, hook, port

In windows we can list the ports that are currently used and the process that are listening to it using the *netstat* command. Just wondering if it is possible to find the exact thread id that opened the port inside the process?

I am looking for programmatic solutions like open process, IPC, etx. In windows if I inject a dll to the process I can get all the windows messages, however it does not include port related events.

Comment: What if it was opened by a thread that doesn't exist any more? (Not a Windows guy, not sure if that is actually possible, but it seems plausible).

Comment: Not sure. Guess the OS would free the port unless the process created the thread still holds it.

Comment: The second is what I meant. A thread opens the port, stores whatever handle you have to it somewhere who's lifetime is *not* tied to that of the thread, then dies (joins or whatever). The program still has the port open, but asking for the id of the thread is not a lot of use, and may be entirely meaningless.

Comment: Thats what I need. I have to see which threads did something on a port. Whether thread is dead or active doesn't bother my needs. A good example I guess would be a web-browser process with multiple tabs running separate threads opening multiple connections. There should be some way the browser process updates the tabs without mixing the response from ports, since HTTP sessions are stateless.

Comment: I am not an expert in these, the opinions or assumption above I made are intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hook `socket`, `bind`, `listen`, `accept` (and `WSAXxx` equivalents) and call GetCurrentThreadId() in the hook handlers. you can leverage e.g. `MS Detours, EasyHook, or MHook` etc to implement your handlers.

Comment: Can hooks catch WSA related events? Have never seen any code that could do that.

Comment: Found one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873658/how-can-i-hook-windows-functions-in-c-c