# How to break on a win32 function call when passed a particular parameter?

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to determine if a handle is being closed so I need to break on a DestroyMenu() call when called with a particular handle.  Using MSVS2013.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: On _any_ call, or only from your code?

Comment: @CodeCaster Any call. But if you have a way to do it from just my code, that would be interesting too.

Comment: Well see for example [How can I hook Windows functions in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873658/how-can-i-hook-windows-functions-in-c-c).

Comment: I've heard of windows hooking but my priorities have changed.  I'll look into this later.  Thanks for your help.