# Injecting to a DX game and make game idle

Tags: winapi, input, directx, xinput

I have a DLL that I am injecting to DX games. In the DLL, I am disabling XInput, raw input and also subclass WndProc to filter a bunch of input messages like WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_INPUT etc. Disabling XInput with XInputEnable(FALSE) and register raw devices with RIDEV_REMOVE flag.

While it works great for some games, it doesn't work for all. Certain games still have mouse move/hover input and I can see hover state for some UI when I move over.

My question is what did I miss? Could the game be capturing input some other ways?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of these possible ways the application may still be receiving mouse input:

- It re-enables Raw Input notifications
- A window other than you one subclassed is receiving the messages
- It's polling `GetCursorPos`
- Using the Windows HID API or other user-mode interface to access the mouse device
- Hooking mouse events or windows message using `SetWindowsHookEx`

The are probably others, but these are all I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Sounds like it is possible for the Game to create another thread and poll for input. Are there any way to get around that? Other than SuspendThread :-)

Comment: It wouldn't have to create another thread to use `GetCursorPos`. It could be called once a frame in the same thread used for rendering.

Comment: So this happens in the game loop. Do you know of any ways to disable that? Sounds impossible to me.

Comment: You can hook `GetCursorPos` and have it return some other value. How to do that is another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873658/how-can-i-hook-windows-functions-in-c-c

Comment: Ok this is not impossible.. but not really practical as it needs to replace system DLL.