# How to collect the contents of a browser's address bar in C / C++?

Tags: c++, c, browser, collect

**Overview**

I wish to collect the contents of a browser's address bar opened by a function in a program in C / C++. There are a few threads here which discuss the matter. However, none seems to be helpful to me.

**My environment**

OS : Windows 7, Windows 10.
Development language : C / C++

**My project**

I am writing an app in which I need to collect data from a server.  The server requires the client to authenticate itself and uses the 2-step *OAuth 2.0* protocol for that. I need to make use of a web API developed by a third party.

The following page describes the whole process.

https://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3/case-study/oauth2-authorization-code

However, I only have a problem with the first step : obtain an authorization code from the server.

A highlight from this page explains the process for the first step, the only one that matters here :

[image]

**Want to see by yourself ?  Try this.**

I have created an account and registered a bogus app on getresponse.com for testing purpose.

- Navigate to the following URL :

  https://app.getresponse.com/oauth2_authorize.html?response_type=code&client_id=41979979-c18b-11ea-bb1c-00163ec8ce26&state=xyz
- Login with :

  Your email : jnj54972@cuoly.com
  Password :   @Aa11111
- On the next screen, Click **Yes**.

After redirection to the example.com site, the next screen shows the following in the address bar :

```
http://example.com/receiver?code=<code>&state=xyz
```

**This code** in the address bar is precisely what I need to continue with the second step of the authentication when this page is displayed in the browser. *Hence the necessity to collect the data contained in the address bar.*

- You can repeat the operation and navigate again to the same URL: you will not have to login again, and you will obtain another authorization code.

(Note : To test the Oauth 2.0 protocol on getresponse.com, I created an app on 9 July 2020. This account has a validity of 30 days. Therefore, the login credentials mentioned above are likely to expire a month after the date of creation.)

**What I have tried so far**

I won't go in details or this post may get too long. But I did try numerous 'curl GET' requests with various parameters. No luck : I never get the browser's address bar data with the code in return.

Can someone help ?

Comment: "I wish to collect the contents of a browser's address bar" - this is non-trivial. Chrome? Internet Explorer? Opera? My own custom web-browser I wrote myself?

Comment: This is an X/Y problem - you say you need to authenticate using OAuth2 (or OIDC, I assume). **You don't need to hijack a user's web-browser to do that**. There are dedicated OAuth2 client libraries that provide simulated web-browsers to work-around the browser-centric nature of OAuth2/OIDC.

Comment: But for your application you should be using an OAuth2 `device` or `client-credentials` authentication mode instead of the human-oriented `code` (authentication-code), `hybrid`, or `implicit` OAuth flows.

Comment: Which browser?  Many browsers don't like other programs invading their space.

Comment: @Dai
I am a complete newbie with OAuth2 and I had no idea that client libraries were available.
You pointed me towards the right direction. I checked and I found several OAuth2 libraries for C / C++.
Could you recommend one that has proven to be functional and efficient ?

Comment: @Morbius No, I cannot make any recommendation, because whatever would work best for you depends entirely on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of ways you could use to accomplish your task:

- [Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873658/how-can-i-hook-windows-functions-in-c-c) a function that changes the address bar text in the browser. This can be achieved using remote dll/code injection and have the injected code send back the results to your main process by using shared memory or [other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) interprocess communications methods
- Get the memory address of the buffer holding the address bar text (memory scanners such as [CE](https://www.cheatengine.org/)) then actively scan for changes in that address for your desired text which in this case is `code=`
- Create a browser extension that listens for url change events in tabs and have it send the results back to your process using sockets preferably